# How to trigger a scroll event with Primeng virtuallScroll

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using virtualScroller with primgeng 7.0 and angular 7. 
What i want to do is when i load the page for the first time, i want to trigger the scroll event and go to a specific page, ex : the second page. Is there a function to do that with angular 7 and primeng and trigger the scrollbar to go to a specific page ? Here's my code :

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="virtualBooks" [scrollable]="true" [rows]="20" scrollHeight="200px" [virtualScroll]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadDataOnScroll($event)"
    [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [virtualRowHeight]="34" [showLoader]="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr style="height:34px">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Component :

```
loadDataOnScroll(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
   this.loading = true;

   // How to triger the scrollbar to go to a specific page ? ex : page 2

   setTimeout(() => {
            this.virtualBooks = this.allBooks.slice(event.first, event.first + event.rows);
            this.loading = false;
        }, 100);      
   }
```